# Ubercart - Stay on page when you add product to cart

Tags: 7, ubercart

In Ubercart, each time i add a product to the cart, i'm redirected to the cart page. Then i have to click on the link "continue shopping". Is there an option to stay on the actual page after adding product to page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
1. Log in as admin, and go to: admin/store/settings/cart
2. Click on Basic Settings
3. Then in the "Add to cart redirect" section, enter: <none>
4. Got to "Continue Shopping Element" and set "Make continue shopping go back to the last item that was added to the cart."
```